# Entity Framework Core thread safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I follow [Generic Repository Pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Generic-Repository-Pattern-f133bca4#content), but on `IRepository`, I use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`:

```
public  interface IRepository<T> where T: BaseEntity
{
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> TableNoTracking { get; }
    T Get(long id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}
```

and implementation class:

```
    public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
        private DbSet<T> entities;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;

        public EFRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this._ctx = context;
            entities = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> Table => this.entities;
    }
```

Service class:

```
public class MovieService : IMovieService
{
        private readonly IRepository<MovieItem> _repoMovie;

        public MovieService(IRepository<MovieItem> repoMovie)
        {
            _repoMovie = repoMovie;
        }

        public async Task<PaginatedList<MovieItem>> GetAllMovies(int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue,
               IEnumerable<int> categoryIds = null)
        {
            var query = _repoMovie.Table;

            if (categoryIds != null)
            {
                query = from m in query
                        where categoryIds.Contains(m.CategoryId)
                        select m;
            }

            return await PaginatedList<MovieItem>.CreateAsync(query, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
}
```

On Startup.cs:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>));           
        services.AddTransient<IMovieService, MovieService>();
        services.AddTransient<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
    }
```

This code throws an error:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

If I switch back to `IEnumerable` on `IRepository`, then it runs fine.

Any idea how to get it to work with `IQueryable`, to make to EF Core to run in the right way ?

```
query = from m in query
        where categoryIds.Contains(m.CategoryId)
        select m;
```

Comment: I guess there could be a conflict on  services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>)); and services.AddTransient<IMovieService, MovieService>(); which will invoke another ef context. If I just drop the service class and use Repository directly, then it's ok.

Answer (score 9):

Entity Framework `DbContext` is not thread safe. You can execute only one query at a time otherwise you will get an exception like you did above.

I suppose that you use your repository multiple times during the same request in parallel that's why you get the exception. If you don't create a transaction per request you can simply make repository transient. In this case new repository will be created for each instance of your service and you will avoid concurrency issue.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>));  but still fails, not sure how to fix it. I've just started the project with a few lines of code and now stuck :D

Comment: I found out that  where categoryIds.Contains(m.CategoryId) cause the problem. If I convert categoryIds.ToList() (from IEnumerable) then it runs ok.

Comment: @namvo, if you retrieve `categoryIds` from DB in a separate query it explains concurrency. Good you found out.

Comment: Tnx, I have spent whole day on this problem, Changing AddScoped to AddTransient for my repos fixed this.

Comment: @Nikola Gaić you have saved my day! thanks a lot. Changing AddScoped to AddTransient worked for me too.

Comment: In your experience, does going from a Scoped to a Transient client create other issues?

Comment: @A.Rowan no, I don't remember any issues with it. Though some developers prefer to create SQL transaction per request. In this case multiple concurrent connections within same transaction will escalate to Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC), which is non desired in most of the cases due to performance and configuration overhead.