# Why is SQLite still not able to write quickly from multiple threads in serialised mode?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, locking, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write records to SQLite using EF Core 2.2 very quickly (1000 rows with a delay of about 20ms) using multiple threads. I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused
>   by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however
>   instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also
>   be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is
>   the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.'

I can use `WAL (Write Ahead Logging)` which works better but still causes the issue, if I use a manual lock with with WAL then it works, but I do not like the inconvenience of having a separate files, which do not get save to the main db if there is a crash. Using a simple lock without WAL also works, but there are freezes for up to a few seconds at a time.

Why does this error happen when the SQLite assembly has been compiled with this config:

```
COMPILER=msvc-1700
DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS
ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
ENABLE_FTS4
ENABLE_FTS5
ENABLE_JSON1
ENABLE_RTREE
THREADSAFE=1
```

`THREADSAFE=1` means serialised according to https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html which should prevent issues when multiple threads are trying to use the same DbContext to write to the db.

> SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1) the SQLite library will itself serialize access
>   to database connections and prepared statements so that the
>   application is free to use the same database connection or the same
>   prepared statement in different threads at the same time.

I would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: The only sane way to do writes from multiple threads is to use multithread mode and have each thread use its own dedicated handle to the database. Trying to share one handle among multiple threads just has too many gotchas and chances for strange interactions, as you're seeing.

Comment: Judging by your error this is an EF issue not a SQLite one. Your pragmas appear correct and SQLite is thread safe, but EF Core is not. See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424674/entity-framework-core-thread-safe)