# Is DBcontext ready to be used?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, thread-safety

In my application, made in asp.net core 2.1, I use `Entity Framework` and thus `ApplicationDB context`.
I get pretty often this error :

```
a second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.
```

Is there any way to find out whether the context is being used by another method ? Something like

```
if(_contex.isAvailable())
```

I do not use asynchronous methods.

**Edit:**
I get my DBcontext using DependecyInjection -

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context { get; set; }
    public BooksRepository(IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _context = context;

    }
```

and my Startup.cs

```
        var dbContext = LoadedServices.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<BooksRepository>(new BooksRepository(LoadedServices.GetService<IConfiguration>(), dbContext));
```

I do not use multiple threads (Iam not aware of it)

Comment: I think you might be opening up a context and not disposing that or savin the changes before starting another one

Comment: Couple of things: how are you creating your context, and is your context accessed from more than one thread? Be aware that DbContext is not thread safe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424674/entity-framework-core-thread-safe

Comment: I have edited my question